# Throw an exception in doInBackground and catch in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an error to be thrown from `doInBackground` method of my `Asynctask`. Is it possible? how can I make it such that the exception would be caught by `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Technically speaking you may be able to use `publishProgress`, but it's simply a hack ;-)

Comment: Maybe if you explain the reason that you want to do this, we can help you find a better way.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot throw exceptions across threads.

However, you can catch the exception in `doInBackground()`, store it somewhere such as a member variable in the asynctask and then handle it in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't throw exception in the background thread.

The much better way is to pass the result returned from the background thread (*if its exception message then let it be*) to the `onPostExecute()` method which then should process the result according to the need.

Comment: *"if its exception message then let it be"*, are you suggesting that if there is an exception, do nothing?

Comment: No, I mean that pass the exception message returned from background thread to the `onPostExecute()` which will then handle it. You can't throw exception from the background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by one of the following three methods:

1. Store the exception as a local variable of the `AsyncTask` subclass, and check for it in the `onPostExecute()` method, as suggested by [laalto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161538/throw-an-exception-in-doinbackground-and-catch-in-onpostexecute/26161591#26161591) and [Peter Pei Guo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161538/throw-an-exception-in-doinbackground-and-catch-in-onpostexecute/26161588#26161588). You can query it's class type and perform different tasks depending on the type of exception. `AsyncTask` guarantees that doing this would be thread-safe.
2. Change the generic result type to `Object` and return either the exception or your result from the `doInBackground()` method, then check the result object's class type in the `onPostExecute()` method, and cast and work on it as appropriate. This is mostly how `FutureTask` (which `AsyncTask` uses internally) implements it's `get()` method, although it stores it's state in a local variable, as it can't rely on the result type.
3. Create a holder class for your result that can be constructed to contain either the result or some specific exceptions, define it's get method to return the result type if available and throw the exception otherwise, then set your `AsyncTask` subclass's generic result type to that class, and catch the exceptions in the `onPostExecute()` method when obtaining the result from the holder.